# Why is there a 60 second delay on my HTTP POST request when using a Go HTTP client?

Tags: http, go, post, http-headers, http-post

My goal is to scrape a website that requires me to log in first using HTTP requests in Golang. I actually succeeded by finding out I can send a post request to the website writing form-data into the body of the request. When I test this through an API development software I use called Postman, the response is instantaneous with no delays. However, when performing the request with an HTTP client in Go, there is a consistent 60 second delay every single time. I end up getting a logged in page, but for my program I need the response to be nearly instantaneous.

As you can see in my code, I've tried adding a bunch of headers to the request like "Connection", "Content-Type", "User-Agent" since I thought *maaaaaybe* the website can tell I'm requesting from a program and is forcing me to wait 60 seconds for a response. Adding these headers to make my request more legitimate(?) doesn't work at all.

Is the delay coming from Go's HTTP client being slow or is there something wrong with how I'm forming my HTTP POST request? Also, was I on to something with my headers and HTTP client is rewriting them when they send out?

Here's my simple program...

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://easypronunciation.com/en/log-in"
    method := "POST"

    payload := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(payload)
    _ = writer.WriteField("email", "foo@bar.com")
    _ = writer.WriteField("password", "*********")
    _ = writer.WriteField("persistent_login", "on")
    _ = writer.WriteField("submit", "")
    err := writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := &http.Client{
        Jar: cookieJar,
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    req.Header.Set("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en-US")
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    f, err := os.Create("response.html")
    defer f.Close()
    res.Write(f)
}
```

Comment: It is definitely not `http.Client` being slow. It could be a lot of other potential causes though, from the network to the request size to the server/proxy/loadbalancer/etc.

Comment: Perhaps there's a problem using a multipart/form-data request body instead of an application/x-www-form-urlencoded request body as used by the website.

Comment: Yea man! This was the issue! Changed my payload and the content-type to urlencoded thingy: the Server Processing latency shot down from ~60200ms to ~175ms . You da best

Answer (score 0):

I doubt, this is the go client library too. I would suggest printing out the latencies for different components and see if/where the 60 second delay is. I would also replace and try different URLs instead